# required is not working

Tags: required

i am trying to set the required if there is no input, but it does not work.

Even if there is no input the button works and does not show the required alert.

How can i fix this issue, can someone help me to fix this !

**Html --**

```
<form id="searchform"> 
        <div style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;" class="col-md-3">
            <input  type="text" id= "nameSearch" name="nameSearch" class="form-control" required >
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> {% trans %}Search{% endtrans %}
        </button>
    </form>
```

**Script --**

```
    $("#submitSearch").on('click', function () {
    var data = {};
    data['nameSearch'] = $('#nameSearch').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/hello/search',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
        ...........
```

Comment: Well, yea your input's class is missing the closing `"` - Also, why is this tagged as php? - And required is usually not put in as a class, you can use it like so: `<input type="text" name="id" class="someClass" required />`

Comment: Your quotations. Close your class tag

Comment: i have update my question, i close the tag " in class="form-control" but it still does not show the required option

Comment: Change your `<button>` to an `<input>` and see if it works - just to prove that it is not the <button> tag that behaves differently

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "show required option" there's nothing to show, only that you are "required" to fill it in, also, what browser are you using? Some browsers don't support HTML5.

Comment: i am using google crome

Comment: i have change my <button> to an <input> but still the required does not working

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: Try and remove the jQuery, I'm not certain but your script is reacting on the button being clicked, not the form being submitted, meaning that even if the "required" function works, the button is still clicked and the script might be executed regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a small anonymous jQuery function to check the HTML5 validity status of a form..

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.isValid = function() {
        return checkValidity();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and then use this in your submit

```
$('#submitSearch').on('click', function(e) {

    if(this.isValid()){

    } else {

    } 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that adding the `required` class wont prevent your form from being submitted.

It looks like you're using Bootstrap, which offers input "validation state" classes, like `has-error`. But this just changes the look of the input, not functionality. See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Have a look at HTML5 form validation: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

And also look whether it will work on the browser you are working with: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"` in `class="form-control"`:

```
<form id="searchform"> 
    <div style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;" class="col-md-3">
        <input  type="text" id= "nameSearch" name="nameSearch" class="form-control" required >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i> {% trans %}Search{% endtrans %}
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried your solution, but it still does not working ...

Answer (score 0):

Your quotations:

```
<input  type="text" id= "nameSearch" name="nameSearch" class="form-control required >
    </div>
```

See this:

```
<input  type="text" id= "nameSearch" name="nameSearch" class="form-control" required >
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried your solution, but it still does not working ...